# Silverlight: Set ComBox index which is inside of a DataGrid from code

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, datagrid, combobox

Is there to set the index of a `ComBox` which is in a `DataGrid` from code? The `ComboBox` in silverlight should be added to the DataGrid using a `DataGridColumnTemplate` so the the `SetValue()` method won't work because it points to the template not the combobox. On the other hand, I can't just name the `ComboBox` and set it's selected index because it is one object and changes will then apply on all the ComboBoxes in the table.

XAML Sample Code:

```
     <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="DG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="421" Margin="10,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="680" ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="CB" >
                            <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
                             ....
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Bindings for this

Say you have a collection of items like the following bound to the ItemsSource of the DataGrid

```
public class GridItem
{
    public int IndexOfSelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

The SelectedIndex of your ComboBox could then be set like this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding IndexOfSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: But how can you have comboboxes whose indexes are differently set? for example the COmboBox in the first row has index set on 1, the second has index set on 12, ...